# Update user profile is not working angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Angular with spring-boot. And I try to update user details from settings page but when click the update button nothing happen, So can someone let me know where is the issue. If you are asking is update function works on backend yeah it works correctly so the problem is in the frontend.

**app.routing**

```
 { path: 'profile-update/:id', component: ProfileUpdateComponent },
```

**SignupData**

```
export interface SignUpData {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    telephone: number;
    roles: string[];
    password: string;
    specialite: string;
    adresses: string[];

  }
```

**user.service**

```
  const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/user/';

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
adresses: string[];
          updateProfile(id: string, userData: SignUpData): Observable<any> {
            return this.http.put(API_URL + 'update/' + id, userData, httpOptions);
          }
```

**update.component.ts**

```
  updateProfile() {
    const {adresse1, ...rest} = this.form;
    const userData: SignUpData = {...rest,  adresses: [adresse1]};
    this.userservice.updateProfile(this.id, userData).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
  onSubmit() { 
    this.updateProfile();
    this.gotoList();   
  }

  gotoList() {
    this.router.navigate(['profile']);
  }
```

**user.html**

```
<form
        name="form"
        (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()"
        #f="ngForm"
        novalidate>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col form-group">
                <label>First name </label>   
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                name="prenom"
                [(ngModel)]="form.prenom"

                #prenom="ngModel"> 
            </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
            <div class="col form-group">
                <label>Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" "
            name="nom"
                [(ngModel)]="form.nom"

                #nom="ngModel">
            </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
      </div> <!-- form-row end.// -->


        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Update </button>
        </div> <!-- form-group// -->      


      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind click event to the update button

```
<button type="submit" (click)="updateProfile()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Update </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I test it also doesn't work btw I already add (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" it does the same work

Comment: I dont see a problem in your html or typescript https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkgtg7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts just created one stackblitz and checked.. but may be the problem is with service i guess can you create a stackblitz and share the code.